# $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real roots of $p^2x^2+2x+p=0$, where $0<p\leq1$. Find the quadratic with roots $1/\alpha+1$ and $1/\beta+1$, in terms of $p$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

> $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of the equation $p^2x^2 + 2x + p = 0$, where $0<p\leq1$, and $\alpha, \beta$ are real numbers. Find the quadratic equation whose roots are $1/\alpha+1$ and $1/\beta+1$, in terms of $p$.

I tried setting

$$p^2x^2 + 2x + p = (x - \alpha)(x - \beta)$$

Then solved to get:

$$p^2x^2 + 2x + p = x^2 - \alpha x -\beta x + \alpha \beta$$

So that means $2 = - \alpha -\beta$, $p = αβ$, and $p^2 = 1$.

Is that correct?

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Are the roots $\frac1{\alpha+1}$ or $\frac1\alpha+1$ ?

Comment: @Callum Alt. hint: if the roots of $\,f(x)=0\,$ are $\,\alpha,\beta$, then the equation with roots $\,g(\alpha), g(\beta)\,$ is $\,f\big(g^{-1}(x)\big)=0\,$. In this case $\,g(x) = \frac{1}{x}+ 1\,$ or $\,g(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}\,$ depending on what you meant to write.

Comment: @Callum: Note that, say, $(z-1)(z-2)$, $5(z-1)(z-2)$, $\frac17(z-1)(z-2)$, $-12345(z-1)(z-2)$ all have the same roots ($z=1$ and $z=2$), but none of the polynomials are *equal*. So, you can't simply write $p^2x^2+2x+p=(x-a)(x-b)$. You have to give the right-hand side a coefficient (namely, $p^2$) to make the leading term match the left-hand side: $p^2x^2+2x+p=p^2(x-a)(x-b)$. This will affect your calculations, but you may be able to proceed from there.

Comment: Vieta's formulas only work like that for monic polynomials, i.e. where $a=1$ in the standard form equation. You can get that here by dividing through by $p^2$, giving: $$x^2 + (2/p^2)x + 1/p = 0$$ From *that* you can use the same logic you previously used to find $\alpha + \beta =-2/p^2$ and $\alpha \beta = 1/p$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the given identities

Given a quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c$,

- Sum of roots is $-b/a$
- Product of roots is $c/a$

Hint: Reduce $\frac{1}{\alpha+1}+\frac{1}{\beta+1}$, and $\frac{1}{\alpha+1}\cdot\frac{1}{\beta+1}$. Note that you know $\alpha+\beta$, and $\alpha\cdot\beta$ from above.

You can construct the quadratic equation from sum, product of roots, using the above points.

Answer (score 4):

One simple way of working this is to just... solve the given equation. No need to do anything fancy, just the good ol' quadratic formula. If we do, we get

$$ \alpha, \beta = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1-p^3}}{p^2}$$

We can assume WLOG that $\alpha$ is the larger root. Then find $\alpha' = 1/\alpha +1, \beta' = 1/\beta +1$ from those:

$$\alpha' = 1+\frac{1}{\alpha} = \frac{p^2-1 + \sqrt{1-p^3}}{-1 + \sqrt{1-p^3}}$$

$$\beta' = \frac{p^2-1 - \sqrt{1-p^3}}{-1 - \sqrt{1-p^3}}$$

*Note*: These equations have been edited from the original ones, which were very, very wrong.

Now you can take those, and substitute them into $(x-\alpha')(x-\beta')=0$. A bit of algebra will get you to your final polynomial.

If you meant to write $1/(\alpha +1), 1/(\beta +1)$, then you'll need to find those instead, but the rest is the same.

Good luck with the rest, I hope to see the final answer from you soon!

Comment: @user21820 The post previously contained more information; I'm uncertain why OP deleted it. I'm going to edit it back in and request a reopen.

Comment: Oh okay thank you very much for informing me. See you around! =)

Comment: I feel like I should post a clarifying note: This is not necessarily the simplest or easiest method. It's merely the one that requires the least thought. :)

Comment: Well since you posted a clarifying note, I also want to make a clarifying comment: You should *not* write "$x = α,β$" because that's mathematically incorrect. Simply delete the "$x =$". I didn't check the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Well here is the hint Suppose $y=\frac{1}{1+a}$ Now solve $a$ in terms of $y$ Now $a$ is root of the equation so $a$ in terms $y$ is a root of the equation so we know $a$ plugs upto 0 yes, you are right you need to make a quadratic in $y$ now and Congratulations you are done!!!
Do it quickly!!!

Answer (score 1):

This question can also be dealt with in terms of function transformations.    We have $ \ f(x) \ = \ p^2x^2 + 2x + p \ = \ 0 \ \  , \ $ with the two real roots $ \ \alpha \ , \ \beta \ \ . \ $  We'll assume for the moment that we seek a quadratic polynomial with the zeroes $ \ \large{\frac{1}{\alpha  \ + \ 1} \ \ , \ \ \frac{1}{\beta \ + \ 1} } \ \ , \ $ since the accepted answer used those.  We can "shift" the function curve for $ \ f(x) \ $ by one unit "to the right" by constructing
$$   f(x - 1) \ \ = \ \ p^2·(x - 1)^2 \ + \ 2·(x - 1) \ + \ p \ \ = \ \ p^2·(x^2 - 2x + 1)  \ + \  (2x - 2) \ + \ p $$
$$ = \ \ p^2· x^2 \ + \ (2 - 2p^2)·x \ + \ (p^2 + p - 2) \ \ , $$

which has the zeroes $ \ \alpha + 1 \ \ , \ \ \beta + 1 \ \ . $

We then use a transformation which is perhaps covered in algebra courses now (it wasn't in my day...).  If we have a quadratic polynomial $ \ x^2 - (r + s)·x + rs \ \  $ with zeroes $ \ r \ , \ s \ \ , \ $ then by "reversing" the order of the coefficients, we produce what is called the *reciprocal* polynomial with zeroes $ \ \frac{1}{r} \ , \ \frac{1}{s} \ \ ; \ $ we see this by writing
$$   rs·x^2 \ - \ (r + s)·x \ + \ 1 \ \ \rightarrow \ \ x^2 \ - \ \frac{r + s}{rs}·x \ + \ \frac{1}{rs} \ \ = \ \ x^2 \ - \ \left( \frac{1}{r} + \frac{1}{s} \right)·x \ + \ \frac{1}{r}·\frac{1}{s} \ \ . $$
So the quadratic polynomial sought is
$$  \mathbf{(p^2 + p - 2)· x^2 \ + \ (2 - 2p^2)·x \ + \ p^2 } \ \ = \ \ (p - 1)·(p + 2)· x^2 \ - \  2·(p - 1)·(p + 1)·x \ + \ p^2 \ \ . $$

As an example for $ \ 0 \ < \ p \ \le \ 1 \ \ , \ \ $ we have for $ \ p \ = \ \frac12 \ \ , \ $
$$ \frac14·x^2 \ + \ 2x \ + \ \frac12 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ \ = \ \ \frac{-2 \ \pm \ \sqrt{7/2}}{1/2} \ \ = \ \ -4 \ \pm \ \sqrt{14}  $$
$$ \rightarrow \ \ \frac14·x^2 \ + \ \frac32·x \ - \ \frac54 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ \ = \ \ \frac{-(3/2) \ \pm \ \sqrt{14/4}}{1/2} \ \ = \ \ -3 \ \pm \ \sqrt{14}  $$
$$ \rightarrow \ \ \frac54·x^2 \ - \ \frac32·x \ - \ \frac14 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ \ = \ \ \frac{+(3/2) \ \pm \ \sqrt{14/4}}{5/2} \ \ = \ \ \frac{3 \ \pm \ \sqrt{14}}{5}  $$
$$ = \ \ \frac{1}{-3 \ \pm \ \sqrt{14}} \ \ = \ \ \frac{-3 \ \mp \ \sqrt{14}}{(-3)^2 \ - \ 14} \ \ . $$

---

If we extend the real numbers to include the "point at infinity" (some people call this $ \ \mathbb{R^{*}} \ ) \ $ , this result still "works". With $ \ p \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ f(x) \ $ becomes the line $ \ 2x \ $ with "zeroes" at $ \ 0 \ $ and $ \ "\infty" \ \ ; \  $ we then have $ \ \frac{1}{\alpha  \ + \ 1} \ = \ 1 \ \ , \ \ " \frac{1}{\beta \ + \ 1}  "  \rightarrow \ 0 \ \ , \ $ which are the zeroes of $ \ -2·x^2 + 2·x \ = \ 2·x·(1 - x) \ \ . \ $  At $ \ p \ = \ 1 \ \ , \ f(x) \ = \ x^2 + 2x + 1 \ = \ (x + 1)^2 \ \ $ with a "double zero" at $ \ x \ = \ -1 \ \ , \ $ and the transformed "polynomial" is the constant $ \ 1^2 \ \ , \ $ which has a "double zero" at $ \ "  \infty  " \ \ . \ $  The innocuous-seeming case of $ \ p \ = \ -2 \ $ has $ \ f(x) \ = \ (-2)^2·x^2 + 2x + (-2) \ = \ 2·(2x^2 - x + 1) \ $ with the zeroes $ \ -1 \ , \ \frac12 \ \ , \ $ for which the transformed polynomial is $ \ -6x + 4 \ \ , \ $ a line with $ \ x-$intercept  $ \ \frac23 \ $ and its second zero at $ \ " \infty " \ \ . $

$$ \ \ $$

We can argue in a similar way for a quadratic polynomial with zeroes
$ \ \frac{1}{\alpha} + 1 \ \ , \ \ \frac{1}{\beta} + 1 \ \ . \ $  We construct the reciprocal polynomial for $ \ f(x) \ $ *first*, producing $ \ p·x^2 + 2x + p^2 \ \ , \ $ then "shift horizontally to the right" by one unit, yielding
$$ p·(x - 1)^2 \ + \ 2·(x - 1) \ + \ p^2 \ \  = \ \ p·x^2 \ + \ (2 - 2p)· x \ + \ (p^2 + p - 2) $$
$$ = \ \ p·x^2 \ + \  2·(1 - p)· x \ + \ (p  + 2)·(p - 1) \ \ . $$
Our earlier example with $ \ p \ = \ \frac12 \ \ $ now gives us

$$ \rightarrow \ \ \frac12·x^2 \ + \ 2·x \ + \ \frac14 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ \ = \ \ \frac{-2 \ \pm \ \sqrt{7/2}}{1} \ \  = \ \ \frac{1}{-4 \ \pm \ \sqrt{14}} \ \ = \ \ \frac{-4 \ \mp \ \sqrt{14}}{(-4)^2 \ - \ 14} \ \ . $$
$$ \rightarrow \ \ \frac12·x^2 \ + \ 1·x \ - \ \frac54 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ \ = \ \ \frac{-1 \ \pm \ \sqrt{7/2}}{1} \ \  . $$
Here, the result for $ \ p \ = \ 1 \ $ is $ \ f(x) \ = \ x^2 + 2x + 1 \ = \ (x + 1)^2 \ \rightarrow \ x^2 \ \ , \ $ with the double zero  $ \ x \ = \ -1 \ $ transformed to the double zero $ \ x \ = \ \frac{1}{-1} + 1 \ = \ 0 \ \ . \ $

So there *is* a little confusion in the problem statement as posted:  if we are to use only roots in $ \ \mathbb{R} \ \ , \ $ the transformed zeroes $ \ \large{\frac{1}{\alpha  \ + \ 1} \ \ , \ \ \frac{1}{\beta \ + \ 1} } \ \ $ only "work" for $ \ 0 \ < \ p \ < \ 1 \ \ , \ $ whereas the transformed zeroes  $ \ \frac{1}{\alpha} + 1 \ \ , \ \ \frac{1}{\beta} + 1 \ \ $ are consistent with the *stated* condition $ \ 0 \ < \ p \ \large{ \le} \normalsize{ \ 1 \ \ . } $